# Sea level static test of an upper stage possible?

Tags: rockets, propulsion, engineering, nozzle

As we know that for the upper stages of the rocket, we need high propulsion efficiency thereby high specific impulse. For that we employ a nozzle with higher expansion ratios.

Now, if we conduct the static tests of such nozzles at sea-level, it will result into an over-expanded plume.

So, how so we get the details of upper-stage engines accurately?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need a massive facility that can maintain a near vacuum while dealing with the engine exhaust. There are (were) a couple in the US.

- [Plum Brook Station](https://www.nasa.gov/centers/glenn/about/testfacilities/index.html) (Part of NASA Glenn) includes the [In-Space Propulsion Facility](https://www1.grc.nasa.gov/facilities/isp/)

[image]

(picture from this informative [paper](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20180005322.pdf))

- [Arnold Engineering Development Center](https://www.arnold.af.mil/About-Us/Fact-Sheets/Display/Article/409286/arnold-engineering-development-complex/) (run by the DOD) includes the [J-6 Large Rocket Motor Test Facility](https://www.arnold.af.mil/About-Us/Fact-Sheets/Display/Article/409282/j-6-large-rocket-motor-test-facility/)
- The never-used [A-3 altitude test stand](https://crgis.ndc.nasa.gov/historic/A-3_Test_Stand) at Stennis, completed to the tune of over $350 million, [even though the program it was designed
  for had been cancelled for three years](https://spacenews.com/nasas-a-3-test-stand-branded-a-349-million-monument-to-its-drift/).

These facilities typically use [steam ejector systems](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/19680001126.pdf#page=35&zoom=auto,-171,21) to keep the test cell pumped down in the presence of huge amounts of exhaust entering it.

[image]

Note: these facilities typically don't claim to produce pure vacuum conditions. Commonly they advertise 100,000 ft (~30 km) altitude conditions (~ 0.2 psi or ~ 0.0014 MPa)

Comment: Wow, this is extreme. Are there any such sites in the former Soviet Union or in Europe? I guess there should be one in Europe, for the development of the Vinci engine.

Comment: Good question, I don't know. I would imagine the Soviets had one. They are expensive to maintain and not used a lot; reading between the lines it seems Plum Brook is falling into disrepair.

Comment: @EverydayAstronaut I would conjecture that nowadays these facilities aren't as important anymore, since there are much better fluid-dynamics simulations available. They give pretty reliable predictions of how the flow in the engine bell will behave. Real tests are still indispendable for the nitty-gritty narrow pipes and certainly for turbopumps, but those operate at such high pressure that I'd expect sea-level vs. vacuum won't make much difference. So, I wouldn't be surprised if most of the development of the Vinci is done without vacuum nozzle, and only a few such tests outsourced to the US.

Comment: The Plum Brook station is limited to engines of 10,000 lbf thrust for a few seconds. The J-2 engine of Saturn V second and third stage had a vacuum thrust of 232,250 lbf.

Comment: @Uwe when Plum Brook was fully working " Rocket  engines producing up to 100,000 lbf thrust may be run for durations up to 270 seconds with the LOX/LH2 propellant combination. "  As I stated in an earlier comment, I don't think the facility has been well maintained.