# How unusual is it to test vacuum engines at sea level?

Tags: spacex, engines, testing, spaceflight-firsts, vacuum

[How are vacuum optimized engines tested without disintegrating them?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/55473/12102) is an excellent question as it's attracted quite a number of informative and diverse answers.

[@Uwe's answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/55477/12102) informs us that there exist  at least one or two low-pressure test chambers where engines can be fired for tens of seconds and the exhaust cleverly managed/diverted to maintain a pressure below 50 Torr for *tens of seconds* which is pretty amazing!

But the news discussed in the linked question says that

> SpaceX recently test fired vacuum optimized raptor engines of starship...  operated in atmosphere

[@PcMan's answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/55475/12102) tells us that this was indeed done at sea level, and says:

> Apparently, the Raptor just bulls its way past the problem by virtue of very high chamber pressure (Meaning the nozzle is not so very overexpanded)

**Question:** How unusual is it to test vacuum engines at sea level? Is this yet another one of the many [spaceflight-firsts](/questions/tagged/spaceflight-firsts) it's pulled off? Or has it been done before?

This may be difficult to answer unambiguously; an engine meant to run in vacuum might be tested with a shorter nozzle at sea level, I don't think that should count. It should be a test that has the same configuration as designed for use in vacuum.

Comment: Do SSMEs count? If so, it was quite common once.

Comment: @OrganicMarble dunno, do space folks call the SSME a vacuum engine? Is its nozzle called a "vacuum nozzle"? I'm not qualified to make the call.

Comment: It's an engine that ran in vacuum. Perhaps the terminology is insufficiently precise.

Comment: @OrganicMarble why does everything Shuttle have to be so exceptional? ;-) I think you can write an answer noting this interesting case, burning continuously from sea-side to orbit, I think that would be *great!*

Comment: The theoretically optimal vacuum nozzle is infinitely long. Which means from a theoretical standpoint, *no* nozzle is truly a "vacuum nozzle" and no engine is truly a "vacuum engine". So, a "vacuum nozzle" always has to be sub-optimal, but then, *every* nozzle is a "vacuum nozzle" and every engine is a "vacuum engine" – just to different degrees. As mentioned, the SSMEs ran from sea-level to orbit. Also, the "sea-level Raptors" on Starship are going to be used for landing in vacuum on the Moon, since the RVacs can't gimbal, so the sea-level Raptors are also going to be running in vacuum.

Comment: It's not so much a question of what is a sea-level engine or a vacuum engine, but which tradeoffs do you make between what you *gain* from better exhaust efficiency vs. what you *lose* because of the larger mass of the larger engine bell. And another consideration for multi-engine clusters: what is the tradeoff between exhaust efficiency and being able to fit more engines into the same spaces if the bells are slightly smaller.