# How to test vaccum engines at sea level?

Tags: spacex, engines, testing

SpaceX is testing its Raptor vacuum engine (RVAC) at sea level (without any facility that can simulate near vacuum conditions). How can they do this without flow separation happening?

Comment: See also https://space.stackexchange.com/q/55487/6944 and https://space.stackexchange.com/q/37749/6944

Comment: Also https://space.stackexchange.com/q/41901/6944